# How can I fix the removeLastQuestion() error?

Tags: javascript, removechild

I am new at JS and I try to remove the last div element that I've created using JS. But there is always this error : Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.The thing is if I enter a number of questions less that the first entered number I delete the number of questions that are more than the last number

```
<span>How many questions you want to add?</span>
<input type="text" id="qNum" >
<div id="containerBlocQ">`</div>
<button onclick="fieldAdd()">Add fields</button>
<button onclick="addNewQues()">Add a questions</button>
<button onclick="removeLastQuestion()">Remove a questions</button>
```

```
function fieldAdd(){
        let qNumber = document.getElementById("qNum").value;
        let containerBlocQ=document.getElementById('containerBlocQ');
        totalNumOfQuest = qNumber - nbQst;
        if(qNumber<=0){
            totalNumOfQuest=0;
        }
        if(totalNumOfQuest>=0){
            for(let i=1; i <= totalNumOfQuest ; i++){
                 addNewQues();
             }

        }
        else{
            for(i=0;Math.abs(totalNumOfQuest);i++){
                //Here is the error
                removeLastQuestion();
                nbQst--;
            }
        }


    }
    function removeLastQuestion(){
        nbQst--;
        let containerBlocQ = document.getElementById('containerBlocQ');
        containerBlocQ.removeChild(containerBlocQ.lastChild);
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] so that your error can be reproduced and debugged (sounds like the `.lastChild` is not a node, but there's not enough information to say why)

Comment: Here the html code:

Comment: <span>How many questions you want to add?</span>
    <input type="text" id="qNum" >
    <div id="containerBlocQ">
        
    </div>
    <button onclick="fieldAdd()">Add fields</button>
    <button onclick="addNewQues()">Add a questions</button>
    <button onclick="removeLastQuestion()">Remove a questions</button>

Comment: Please post all code relevant to the question *in the question* (not in the comments), per SO rules, thanks

Comment: The thing is if I enter a number of questions less that the first entered number I delete the number of questions that are more than the last number

Comment: I hope it's clear now

Comment: Shall activating `removeLastQuestion()` twice in a row do something useful?